# scrapy list index out of range cause price sometimes not exists

Tags: python, scrapy

What can i do about that error i get sometimes?

`list index out of range`

This comes sometimes, when there is no price on an item cause its not available on amazon.

Thats my code

```
def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonMobileDetailsItem()

        # for href in response.css('div.s-search-results'):
        # Extracting details
        name = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-color-base.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()
        price = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-price:nth-child(1) .a-price-whole').css('::text').extract()
        link = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-section h2 .a-link-normal::attr(href)').extract()
        imagelink = response.css('div.s-search-results .s-image::attr(src)').extract()

        # Passing it to items dictionary
        items['name'] = name
        items['price'] = price
        items['site'] = ['amazon.de']
        items['link'] = link
        items['imagelink'] = imagelink

        yield items
```

It is working but with that error and when that comes, all my results are going wrong :/

if already tried that

```
if(price and link and name and imagelink):
            # Passing it to items dictionary
            items['name'] = name
            items['price'] = price
            items['site'] = ['amazon.de']
            items['link'] = link
            items['imagelink'] = imagelink

            yield items
```

But doesnt help :/

The error comes cause not every product on amazon has `.a-price-whole`
But can i jump to the next one if i get that error or something?

I only want to skip that items if there is no price, or no name or something

Answer (score 2):

Why did you add **separate** `.css('::text')` call?
Try this:

```
response.css('div.s-search-results .a-price:nth-child(1) .a-price-whole::text').extract()
```

Also are you sure that you need `.extract()` and not `.extract_first()` (or `.get()`)?

Comment: idk why i use .css ::text, it works also like your example.

But .get() and extract_first give errors... ```object of type 'NoneType' has no len()``` for each name and something

Comment: Where did you use `len()`?

Comment: in my pipeline here ```def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            for i in range(len(item['name'])):```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try` statement and catch the `IndexError` and set price to be some value that represents "No Price Found"

```
def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonMobileDetailsItem()

    # for href in response.css('div.s-search-results'):
    # Extracting details
    name = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-color-base.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()
    try:
       price = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-price:nth-child(1) .a-price-whole').css('::text').extract()
    except IndexError as e: 
       print(e) #So you know that there was an error in the script while its running
       price = -9999999 #Some random value that represents no price yet
    link = response.css('div.s-search-results .a-section h2 .a-link-normal::attr(href)').extract()
    imagelink = response.css('div.s-search-results .s-image::attr(src)').extract()

    # Passing it to items dictionary
    items['name'] = name
    items['price'] = price
    items['site'] = ['amazon.de']
    items['link'] = link
    items['imagelink'] = imagelink

    yield items
```

Comment: I dont know why, but it doesnt help... he never used the price -999999...